# Como enviar via ajax o valor da opção selecionada num select?

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho dois selects, uma para estados e outro para cidades.

Quero pegar o valor do select de estados com o evento change, enviá-lo via ajax e recuperar as cidades que 
tem o valor correspondente.

O único erro que está dando no meu código é dizer que a variável que envio via post está indefinida

Seguem os códigos e o erro:

```
<select name="Estado" id="estado" class="campo selectEstado form-control">
    <option value="">Selecione seu estado</option>
    // Outros options
 </select>

<select name="Cidade" id="cidade" class="campo selectCidade form-control">
    <option value="">Selecione sua cidade</option>
    // Outros options
 </select>


$('#estado').on('change',function(){
        var uf = $("#estado option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "scripts/retornaMunicipio.php",
            data: uf,
            success:function(data){
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(data.retorno, function (i) {
                // código
             });

                                    },
            error:function(data){
            }
        });
    });
```

Arquivo retornaMunicipio.php

```
$uf = $_POST["uf"];
// Esse uf não está sendo definido
```

Segue o erro:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: uf in C:\inetpub\teste\httpdocs\retornaMunicipio.php on line 15
```

O meu único problema é esse, essa variável `$uf` não está recebendo o valor enviado pelo ajax. Os caminhos dos arquivos estão certos. Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "scripts/retornaMunicipio.php",
        data: {uf: uf},
        success:function(data){
           data = $.parseJSON(data);
           $.each(data.retorno, function (i) {
            // código
           });
        },
        error:function(data){
        }
    });
```

Comment: exatamente isso!

Comment: Pode me explicar o porque disso?

Comment: Você precisa dizer o que você vai mandar e o valor que vai mandar, por exemplo:
data: {estado: uf}
Desta forma la no PHP você iria pegar assim $uf = $_POST['estado'];